# opencv distance from camera to object calculation off by 4"

Tags: python, opencv, math

Hello there people of the internet,
When I run the following code the measurement is either + or - 4" depending on the distance between the camera and the little hello world piece of paper that I stuck to the wall. The measurement is consistently off by 4" regardless of how far away the camera is from the 8.5" x 11" piece of paper on the wall.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2
import time
import os


def find_marker(image):
    #conver the image into grayscales, blurs it then detects edges
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 35, 125)

    #find the contours in the edged image and keep the largest one;
    #w'll assume that this our piece of paper in the image
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    c = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)

    #compute the bounding box of the paper region and return it
    return cv2.minAreaRect(c)

def distance_to_camera(knownWidth, focalLength, perWidth):
    #compute and return the distance from the marker to the camera
    return (knownWidth * focalLength) / perWidth


#intialize the known distances from the camera to the object
KNOWN_DISTANCE = 22

#initialize the known object width, which in this case the piece of paper is 12 inches
KNOWN_WIDTH = 11

#load the first image that contains an object that is known to be 2 feet
#from our camera, the find the paper marker in the image and
#initialize the focal length
rootimage = cv2.imread("/Volumes/404/final_rov_code/Python/images/2ft.jpg")
marker1 = find_marker(rootimage)
marker2 = marker1[0][1] - marker1[1][1]
focalLength = (marker2 * KNOWN_DISTANCE) / KNOWN_WIDTH
print(marker1)
print(marker2)
image = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.startWindowThread()
keyboard = Controller()

        #Loop over the image
while True:
    #load the image, find the marker in the image then compute the
    #distance to the marker from the camera
    ret, frame = image.read()
    marker = find_marker(frame)
    inches = distance_to_camera(KNOWN_WIDTH, focalLength, marker[1][0])
    print(inches)
    #draw a bounding box around the image and display it
    box = cv2.boxPoints(marker)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, "%.2fin" % inches,
        (frame.shape[1] - 200, frame.shape[0] - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        2.0, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    plt.imshow(frame)
    plt.show()
    keyboard.press('q')
    keyboard.release('q')
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Above is the code me and my team are using. below is a picture of the paper on the wall with the incorrect measurement. [image]
Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: did you undistort the lens? why is  knownwidth=11 when in comment it is 12? 2ft name of the image sounds as if knowndist should be 24?!?

Comment: ok, since you mention the marker to be 11 inches several times this is probably ok. But if the reference dist is 2ft, KNOWN_DISTANCE still should be 24 (if google is right with 1ft = 12 inches. Sorry, I'm in metrical system).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few possible sources of the error:

The equation you're using assumes that you're facing dead on with the reference tag. Rotating around the paper (looking at it from the left or right) also decreases the pixel width even if you aren't any further from it.

The resolution of the camera bounds your accuracy. It probably isn't contributing much to the error, but your perWidth measurement is in pixels so it's constrained by the resolution.

Double check your focalLength calculation. Possibly do it multiple times at different distances and average the results.

If you want to locate your position (topdown, (x,y,theta)) you'll want three reference points. Even three collinear points will give you a unique position (aside from the symmetry point on the other side of the tags).